# How to override global CSS class in the local

Tags: css, global-variables, overriding, local

I have a global variable defined for the list and is referenced in my html

```
ol>li::before, ul>li::before {
color: #FFFFFF;
content: '\00A7';
display: inline-block;  
position: absolute;
}
```

I am trying to override this in my html as I have to remove just this line:

```
content: '\00A7';
```

If I simply use it in my local file it doesn't override. 
Any suggestions on how do I fix this?

Comment: you can try ol>li::before, ul>li::before {content: initial !important!}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have three ways to achieve it.

1. add `!important` after your own css in your css file

```css
ol>li::before, ul>li::before {
content: '\00A7' !important;
}
```

2. add the css after the global css in your html

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="global.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="my.css">
```

3. add a tag in your html element

```html
<ol my-tag>
...
</ol>
```

```css
ol[my-tag]>li::before{
    // your own css
}
```